# Jenkins Pipeline Git SCM: status code 129: error: wrong number of arguments, should be 2

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline job that is polling a Git SCM on a Windows master / slave machine.

When a build is triggered, the build job fails due to an incorrect number of arguments passed to Git.

I work in a team that has been using SVN as the code version control system and Jenkins Freestyle projects for their autobuild system for several years. In the Freestyle jobs, they were set up to poll the SCM every 15 minutes.

In a step to modernise our build system, I decided to move to using Git and Jenkins Pipelines (not Multibranch).

I have installed Git 2.21.0.windows.1 on all participating machines (master and slave nodes that have appropriate labels). The master machine is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, and the slave nodes are running Windows 10 Pro. The Jenkins master is running Jenkins ver. 2.164.2. In "Global Tool Configuration", the path to Git is "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe". The quotes are intended as there is a space in "Program Files". The plugin versions are:

- Pipeline: API - 2.33
- Pipeline: Groovy - 2.67
- Git client plugin - 2.7.7
- Git plugin - 3.10.0
- GIT server Plugin - 1.7
- Pipeline - 2.6
- SCM API Plugin - 2.4.1

I have set up my Jenkins Pipeline jobs to poll the Git server master branch every 15 minutes for changes. When changes are detected, a build is triggered on a slave machine.

However, I notice when a build is trigger, I get this error and the build fails before my Jenkinsfile is even executed.

This is the console output with the actual links to my git repo redacted. Any redaction is surrounded by <>.

```
Started by an SCM change
Checking out git <LINK_TO_GIT_SCM> into d:\jenkins\workspace@script to read <PROJECT_NAME>/Jenkinsfile
using credential 8f54635c-fe91-43d8-a400-57e9d1e7fa4c
Cloning the remote Git repository
Honoring refspec on initial clone
Cloning repository <LINK_TO_GIT_SCM>
 > "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" init d:\jenkins\workspace@script\<PROJECT_NAME> # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from <LINK_TO_GIT_SCM>
 > "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials (Git server)
 > "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" fetch --tags --force --progress <LINK_TO_GIT_SCM> +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master # timeout=60
 > "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" config remote.origin.url <LINK_TO_GIT_SCM> # timeout=10
 > "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" config --add remote.origin.fetch  # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command ""C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" config --add remote.origin.fetch " returned status code 129:
stdout: 
stderr: error: wrong number of arguments, should be 2
usage: git config [<options>]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
    --worktree            use per-worktree config file
    -f, --file <file>     use given config file
    --blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object

Action
    --get                 get value: name [value-regex]
    --get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
    --get-regexp          get values for regexp: name-regex [value-regex]
    --get-urlmatch        get value specific for the URL: section[.var] URL
    --replace-all         replace all matching variables: name value [value_regex]
    --add                 add a new variable: name value
    --unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]
    --unset-all           remove all matches: name [value-regex]
    --rename-section      rename section: old-name new-name
    --remove-section      remove a section: name
    -l, --list            list all
    -e, --edit            open an editor
    --get-color           find the color configured: slot [default]
    --get-colorbool       find the color setting: slot [stdout-is-tty]

Type
    -t, --type <>         value is given this type
    --bool                value is "true" or "false"
    --int                 value is decimal number
    --bool-or-int         value is --bool or --int
    --path                value is a path (file or directory name)
    --expiry-date         value is an expiry date

Other
    -z, --null            terminate values with NUL byte
    --name-only           show variable names only
    --includes            respect include directives on lookup
    --show-origin         show origin of config (file, standard input, blob, command line)
    --default <value>     with --get, use default value when missing entry


    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2010)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2006)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1638)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1650)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:658)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1152)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:293)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is how my Pipeline gets the Jenkinsfile.

[image: Pipeline Definition].

I expect the build to be triggered and Git SCM to successfully fetch the latest changesets with the correct number of arguments. When I run the culprit line in the command line on the slave machine:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" config --add remote.origin.fetch  # timeout=10
```

I get the same error. I can't tell if I have installed incompatible Git versions or my set up is incorrect.

Comment: What is the code for the git actions?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I've added a picture of my Pipeline Definition. The Git actions are generated by Pipeline SCM I believe. None of my code (Jenkinsfile) is called.

Comment: If I run the command:

"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" config --add remote.origin.fetch  #

Without the timeout argument, it runs fine...